# Prove the assertion on the game theory.

Tags: self-learning, game-theory

[image]

> > if a dominant strategy for player1  is added to finite normal form game then the payoff to player1 at any equlibrium of the new game must be at least as great as any nash equlibrium payoff of player1 in the orginal game.

This statement is true or not? Please show me its proof. Thank you.

Comment: Is there exactly one player?

Comment: Yes, the question says so @mathse can you please show it?

Comment: The question says that there is only one player? :) (What is a _finite_ normal form game?)

Comment: Yes, it mentions just "player1". But because of a finite normal form game, I need to second Player. @mathse

Comment: Then, the statment is false. And this is its explanation. Right? Well, how to explain it by a counter example?

Comment: This is what is bad about economics. The questions are not well-defined. Then how can one expect a well-defined answer? Do you copy this word by word from the exercise or did you miss something?

Comment: I Will post the question as a photo Dear @mathse

Comment: I posted it @mathse

Comment: Yes, somewhere your book must have defined what a finite game is. I think it is one with finitely many players?

Comment: Yes, on my notes, it defines as you said. Well, what should I answer this question? @mathse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is false.

Consider a two-player game where player $1$ has only one action $L$ and player $2$ has two actions, $A$ and $B$. Let payoffs be as follows:

$\begin{array}{lcl}
 & L \\ 
A& (1^*,1)\\
B & (5^*,5^*)
\end{array}
$

Now, add the following dominant strategy $R$ for player $1$

$\begin{array}{lccc}
 & L & R\\ 
A& (1,1) & (2^*,500^*)\\
B & (5,5^*) & (6^*,0)\\
\end{array}
$

Player $1$ is worse off in the only Nash equilibrium of the new game.

Comment: Okay thank you so much:)